# What is "a great way" to write this discriminated union, minimizing repetition?

Tags: typescript

This is coming out of a simple react native screen, but what I'm looking for is a pattern/template that accomplishes this goal:

- Action type, a discriminated union for each redux action
- functions to create each Action

I've tried a few patterns and haven't found one I like, but I'm new to TypeScript (I'm coming from Swift and Elm) and so I thought someone would have a great solution.  Here's what I'm using now:

```typescript
enum Name {
  SET_CURRENT_LOCATION = "main.SET_CURRENT_LOCATION",
  SET_IS_MODAL_VISIBLE = "main.SET_IS_MODAL_VISIBLE",
  TOGGLE_MODAL_VISIBLE = "main.TOGGLE_MODAL_VISIBLE",
}

type SetCurrentLocation = { name: Name.SET_CURRENT_LOCATION; value: LocationData | null }
type SetModalVisible = { name: Name.SET_IS_MODAL_VISIBLE; value: boolean }
type ToggleModalVisible = { name: Name.TOGGLE_MODAL_VISIBLE }

export type Action =
  | SetCurrentLocation
  | SetModalVisible
  | ToggleModalVisible

export function setCurrentLocation(value: LocationData | null): Action {
  return {
    name: Name.SET_CURRENT_LOCATION,
    value,
  }
}

export function showModal(): Action {
  return {
    name: Name.SET_IS_MODAL_VISIBLE,
    value: true,
  }
}

export function hideModal(): Action {
  return {
    name: Name.SET_IS_MODAL_VISIBLE,
    value: false,
  }
}

export function toggleModal(): Action {
  return {
    name: Name.TOGGLE_MODAL_VISIBLE,
  }
}

export function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.name) {
    case Name.SET_CURRENT_LOCATION:
      return { ...state, currentLocation: action.value }
    case Name.SET_IS_MODAL_VISIBLE:
      return { ...state, isModalVisible: action.value }
    case Name.TOGGLE_MODAL_VISIBLE:
      return { ...state, isModalVisible: !state.isModalVisible }
  }
}
```

This is a **best practice / elegant patterns** question, not a data modeling one.  Please excuse any copy/paste errors.

*Edit:* I removed the pseudo-code second snippet because it detracted from the question and added confusion

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve in the short example? `Action` does not have `value` property and your're using it in `reducer`. Where do you expect implementation of, for example `SetModalVisible(value:  boolean)` to be? It would help if you're more clear.

Comment: Please consider modifying the example code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about.  Right now there are missing declarations for `LocationData` and `State`.  Good luck!

Comment: Seems like the perfect way to model a discriminated union: A tag key (`name`) and a value key (which is typed according to the discriminator).

If you want more elegant syntax, reasonml and bucklescript provide almost exactly the syntax you're looking for and also compile to js.

Comment: @Nenad The second code snippet is not working code - it’s an example of what I would **ideally** write (no repetition of name constants, no need for both function and type declarations). If you are familiar with Elm code, this would look very familiar, I’m trying to find out if it is possible in TS

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the suggestion, but I’m afraid you’ve missed the point of my question - not to analyze the code but to decrease the repetition of the constants and, in general, the many identical names.

Comment: @Artyer This is more along the lines of what I was looking for, thank you! I was hoping for “Vanilla TS” but hooking into the compiler API to do some meta programming sounds like the best route.

Comment: @Artyer Ah no those are not what I expected. I can already model this example in Elm perfectly, I’m looking for TS code that is functionally equivalent to the first code snippet, but is shorter and less repetitive, like the second snippet.

Comment: In order to begin to work on decreasing the repetition, I would prefer to start with something that has no errors in my IDE.  If you're saying you'd like someone to suggest an answer without being able to try it out themselves, that's fine, but not how I like to do things.  In any case, good luck to you.

Comment: Tomorrow I’ll try this out using decorators

Comment: @colinta I understand it's hypothetical example, but it's not doing the same thing original example is doing. Perhaps, if you post working and compatible versions of TypeScript (verbose version) and Elm example (how you would like it to look), we could suggest something.

Comment: @Nenad the second snippet is doing the same thing, but much terser, but it’s pseudo-code since I don’t know the best way to accomplish this. An Elm example would look very similar, so I’ll add comments to the code to make it clearer what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Better yet I’ll just remove it - it wasn’t anything close to working code, and just provided a source of confusion.